# How do I access the user object inside the model serializer of django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a task for nested insertion. I have figured out that by overriding the create method in serializer. But I need to have user email for insertion. How do I get the email in serializer efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serializers are passed a context dictionary, which contains the view instance, so you could get the `user` by doing something like this:

```
request = self.context.get('request', None)
    if request is not None:
        email = request.user.email
```

Comment: It looks quite simple. Thanks a lot!! 
There's one more case to it, it can be phone sometimes instead of email. Can I use variable to get it or I will have to put condition?